# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un email con php7 desde localhost?

Tags: php, php7, email

Quiero hacer una prueba para enviar un email cuando el usuario se registra.

Me gustaría saber cómo implementarlo y si hay algún recurso en concreto para llevar a cabo esta función.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Muéstranos qué has intentado. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar el tipo de servidor de correo que usas y qué has intentado? La biblioteca de funciones más ampliamente usada en PHP es, sin lugar a dudas, [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Te recomiendo pasarte por su [documentación](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/README.md) y [los ejemplos](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples) para ver su uso y configuración.

Comment: Disculpa que insista. Cuando haces referencia a "desde localhost" te refieres a tu entorno de desarrollo local, pero no nos has indicado ni el sistema operativo que usas para desarrollar ni la distribución AMP que estás usando: WampServer, XAMPP, [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/wsl/install-win10), paquetes de la distribución en sistemas operativos Linux como RedHat, Debian o derivados, etc. Nos sería de gran ayuda conocer estos datos para poder ayudarte, pero aún más conocer tu proveedor de correo electrónico para facilitarte código inicial para un ejemplo de uso de PHPMailer.

Comment: Uso XAMPP y cómo S.O windows 10.

Comment: Gracias por la información, agregaré a tu pregunta. Como dije, *nos sería de gran ayuda conocer estos datos para poder ayudarte* (gracias), pero **aún más conocer tu proveedor de correo electrónico** para facilitarte código inicial para un ejemplo de uso de PHPMailer.

Comment: El proveedor de correo electrónico usa 'webmail.midominio', configurado con smtp e imap, con los puertos 587.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siempre puedes utilizar la función

> mail()

de php sin necesidad de librerias externas.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php

Comment: La mejor respuesta, antes de complicarse la vida viendo frameworks y librerías, es mejor conocer y utilizar lo básico.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], aunque correcta debido a la extensión y contenido me parece de baja calidad

Comment: Carlos, por desgracia esa función sólo funciona en máquinas con un [MTA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_de_correo) instalado y por norma general interfiere con estándares como [SPF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), [DKIM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) y [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC). Usando esta función hay una alta probabilidad de que deje de funcionar al cambiar del servidor de desarrollo a un alojamiento web externo e incluso que los mensajes lleguen a la bandeja de SPAM o sean completamente descartados.

Answer (score 1):

## Resumen del soporte de envío de correo electrónico en PHP

PHP provee dos métodos nativos para el envío de correo electrónico:

- [`mail()`](https://php.net/es/function.mail)
- [`imap_mail()`](https://php.net/es/function.imap-mail)

Existen multitud de métodos adicionales. Entre ellos destaco:

- [`PEAR::Mail`](https://pear.php.net/package/Mail)
- [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

## Ventajas e inconvenientes:

A continuación enumeraré las ventajas e inconvenientes de cada uno de los métodos anteriores. He destacado lo más relevante, aunque podrían haber detalles que he considerado de poca consideración para incluirlos.

Si pensáis que hay que agregar una ventaja o inconveniente a alguno de los métodos, por favor, os ruego que editéis mi respuesta y los agreguéis o bien me dejéis un comentario para editarlo yo mismo.

---

**`mail()`:**

- Ventajas:

  - Todas las versiones de PHP proveen la función.
  - Con una única llamada a la función podemos enviar un correo electrónico en texto plano*.
- Desventajas:

  - Sólo funciona si existe un MTA configurado en la máquina donde se aloja la página web (como *postfix*, *sendmail*, *exim4*, etc) o se configuran la [dirección de un servidor SMTP en `php.ini`](https://php.net/es/mail.configuration#ini.smtp) para apuntar a un MTA en configuración [*open relay*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_relay) completa o por restricción de IP de origen.
  - Si el MTA usado para enviar correo electrónico no está dado de alta en las políticas [SPF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) y no está configurada la firma de mensajes a través de [DKIM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) y/o el dominio tiene configurado [DMARC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC), es probable que tu mensaje de correo sea descartado en el destino o enviado a la carpeta de SPAM.

(*) Siempre y cuando esté correctamente configurado el servidor PHP atendiendo las consideraciones del apartado "desventajas".

---

**`imap_mail()`:**

- Ventajas:

  - Todas las versiones de PHP proveen la función.
  - Con una única llamada a la función podemos enviar un correo electrónico en texto plano y/ enriquecido (HTML)*.
- Desventajas:

  - No todos los proveedores de correo electrónico permiten en acceso IMAP a sus buzones de correo.
  - No todos los proveedores de correo electrónico permiten el envío de correo a través de IMAP.

(*) Proporcionado en línea el contenido de las matrices asociativas de entrada y la conexión al servidor IMAP haya sido previamente establecida correctamente.

---

**`PEAR::Mail`:**

- Ventajas (*):

  - Soporta usar internamente la función `mail()`, `sendmail` o un servidor `SMTP`.
  - Permite enviar archivos adjuntos ([ver ejemplo](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php)).
  - Migrar el código de un servidor a otro es trivial si hacemos descarga local de archivos (en vez de instalar los paquetes PEAR a nivel global) ya que los parámetros de configuración se mantienen.
- Desventajas (*):

  - No todos los proveedores de correo electrónico permiten el envío de correo electrónico a través de sus servidores (hoy en día es muy raro encontrar alguno que no lo permita).
  - No todos los proveedores permiten conexiones salientes SMTP a servidores externos (también es muy raro encontrar algún servidor así hoy en día).

(*) Específicas, en su caso, de SMTP.

---

**`PHPMailer`:**

- Ventajas (*):

  - Soporta usar internamente la función `mail()`, `sendmail`, un servidor `SMTP` y, además, no requiere de un MTA local para enviar emails ya que expone la clase `SMTP` para poder acceder a servidores remotos de manera directa ([ver ejemplo](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp_check.phps)).
  - Permite enviar archivos adjuntos ([ver ejemplo](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps)).
  - Permite firmar en origen los mensajes de correo electrónico usando `DKIM`.
  - Migrar el código de un servidor a otro es trivial si hacemos descarga local de archivos ya que los parámetros de configuración se mantienen.
  - Si se usa `composer` migrar el código también es sencillo y, además, se mantiene el código actualizado.
- Desventajas (*):

  - No todos los proveedores de correo electrónico permiten el envío de correo electrónico a través de sus servidores (hoy en día es muy raro encontrar alguno que no lo permita).
  - No todos los proveedores permiten conexiones salientes SMTP a servidores externos (también es muy raro encontrar algún servidor así hoy en día).

(*) Específicas, en su caso, de SMTP.

---

## Conclusión

Yo, personalmente, recomiendo hacer uso de `PHPMailer` a través de [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-macos) ya que a día de hoy es el proyecto que más se usa, tiene una gran documentación y un amplio catálogo de ejemplos y el mantenimiento del código está respaldado por una comunidad muy amplia que aporta tanto informe de problemas de funcionamiento o seguridad, como soluciones a dichos problemas.

Comment: Solo para completar, decir que la función `mail` de PHP devuelve true o false. Pero eso significa que confirma la ejecución de salida del mail, NO confirma la llegada al destino.es un detalle a tener en cuenta ( ya se ha hablado varias veces de ello en SO.)

Comment: Gracias, aunque no se aplica únicamente a `mail()`, es común para todos los métodos de envío. Siempre se comprueba que el mensaje sea entregado al MTA, no que llegue a su destino.